# php split array of strings to <ul><li>

Tags: php

Hi I'm having the problem that I have an array list of strings which contains the path to .txt files on my server.

example:

```
// list all textfiles
$list = findFiles(dirname(__FILE__), array ("txt") );
// sort list
array_multisort($list["txt"], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING );
// iterate through list and print out found files as ul-li list
foreach ($list["txt"] as $file_entry) {

echo '<li>$file_entry</li>\n';

}
```

This gets me something like that:

```
<li>path1\path\chek.txt</li>
<li>path1\path\test\check2.txt</li>
<li>path1\path1\test\check.txt</li>
<li>path2\test\pt\check1.txt</li>
<li>path2\test\pt\check2.txt</li>
<li>path2\test\check2.txt</li>
<li>path2\path2\check.txt</li>
<li>path2\path3\dir.txt</li>
<li>path2\path3\test\check.txt</li>
<li>path3\path3\test\check1.txt</li>
```

I want to "convert" that array to something which looks like an directory tree (to make later use of some jquery plugin [e.g. [http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jquery-tree-control/]](http://filamentgroup.com/examples/jquery-tree-control/) ):

```
<ul>
<li>path1
<ul>
    <li>path</li>
       <ul> 
          <li><a href="$_SERVER[php_self]?file=fullpathtofile">check.txt</a></li>
       </ul>
    <li>path1</li>
...
```

So the question is how to make such a directory list from my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got, by transforming the paths into nested arrays, then merging them recursively, then formatting using a recursive function to print it out as a list;

```
$list['txt'] = array(
    'path1\path\chek.txt',
    'path1\path\test\check2.txt',
    'path1\path1\test\check.txt',
    'path2\test\pt\check1.txt',
    'path2\test\pt\check2.txt',
    'path2\test\check2.txt',
    'path2\path2\check.txt',
    'path2\path3\dir.txt',
    'path2\path3\test\check.txt',
    'path3\path3\test\check1.txt'
);

$paths = array();
foreach ($list['txt'] as $file_entry) {
    $path = explode('\\', $file_entry);
    $pathArr = $file_entry;
    for ($i = count($path) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $pathArr = array($path[$i] => $pathArr);
    }
    $paths = array_merge_recursive($paths, $pathArr);
}

function to_list($paths, $depth = 0) {
    echo str_repeat("\t", $depth) . "<ul>\n";
    foreach ($paths as $entry => $value) {
        echo str_repeat("\t", $depth + 1) . '<li>';
        if (is_array($value)) {
            echo "$entry\n";
            to_list($value, $depth + 2);
            echo "\n" . str_repeat("\t", $depth + 1);
        } else {
            echo "<a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?file=$value\">$entry</a>";
        }
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    echo str_repeat("\t", $depth) . "</ul>\n";
}
to_list($paths);
```

Comment: Thank you this works. The only thing is missing is the full path to the file in the statement 'echo "<a>$entry</a>";'  any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah, that should be possible by assigning the full file path as the value at the end of the `$pathArr`, then using that path in the href. I'll update my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should better "explode" every string to an array() using "\" as delimiter, than you merge all table ton one multi-array.

```
['path1']=>['path']=>"chek.txt"
        =>['path']=>['test']=>"check2.txt"
        =>['path']=>['test']=>"check.txt"
```

...

finaly for every new array you add an `"<ul>"` tag !